# PHP: Shorter GET-Variable access

Tags: php, post, request

At the moment I am accessing my editing script like this:

```
http://example.com/editStuff.php?id=1234

$id = $_REQUEST["id"];
echo($id);                //write: 1234
```

I would like to access the scripts like this:

```
http://example.com/editStuff.php?1234
```

I thought of splitting the URL on `?`, but you probably know an easier way.
Do you know a way to realize this?

Comment: $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] has what you need

Comment: Look in `array_keys($_GET)`

Comment: You might want to use mod_rewrite. With mod_rewrite you would have URL's like: http://example.com/stuff/edit/1234

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use [`$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) as follows:

```
$id = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
echo $id;
```

From the Docs:

> The query string, if any, via which the page was accessed.